# Approximating longest path on graphs with average degree n/2

Tags: approximation

I have a graph with average degree $n/2$. How I can find an approximation algorithm for the longest path problem with factor $1/4$?

Comment: What are your thoughts on the question? Can you come up with *any* approximation algorithm at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is something to get you started.

Suppose that your graph were $n/2$-regular, and consider the following algorithm. Start at an arbitrary vertex $v_1$. Choose one of its $n/2$ neighbors $v_2$. Choose one of $v_2$'s $n/2$ neighbors $v_3 \neq v_1$. And so on. The process will continue for at least $n/2+1$ steps. Since every path has length at most $n$, this gives a $1/2$ approximation. In fact, this would work even if the *minimal* degree were at least $n/2$.

Comment: can you explain the sentence :The process will continue for at least n/2+1 steps.?

Comment: The process will continue as long as there is always a neighbor that don’t already belong to the path.

Comment: In my question average degree is n/2 but your prove has n/2-regural graph,if you can send solve of my question.thanks.it's not homework plz help for solve this

Comment: I cannot "solve your question". It is you who should solve *your* question. I gave you something to start with. You should now spend some reasonable amount of time on the question, trying to solve it on your own.

Comment: Where did you encounter the question, by the way?